# PJSUA --null-audio for python bindings

Tags: python, pjsip

How does one specify --null-audio option working with python API (http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP_Tutorial)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow you're wasting hours of time searching and then, desperate, you post a question to Stackoverflow, and the *exact moment after it* you find an answer by yourself. This place is the most useful problem solver ever.

After you've created your lib, call lib.set_null_snd_dev(). That must be done after making lib.init (here's my example:)

```
lib = pj.Lib()
lib.init(log_cfg=pj.LogConfig(level=3, callback=log_cb))
lib.set_null_snd_dev()
```

Comment: How do we set without null audio option in Python? To make it working mode instead of dummy mode? i tried this but did not worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483635/pjsip-new-call-error-unable-to-find-default-audio-device-pjmedia-eaud-nodef

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to check out that possible solution I've posted in your thread.