# Linux - Without hardware soundcard, capture audio playback, and record it to file

Tags: linux, ubuntu-server, pyaudio

Is such a thing even possible?

Is there a possibility to create a virtual sound card and then use for example PyAudio to listen to its output and save it to a file? NOTE that there is no hardware soundcard present on the machine.

I have tried a lot of things, especially `snd-dummy` ALSA module, but I am starting to doubt if I am looking for the right tools. I would be grateful if someone could point me towards at least high-level solution. Preferably something that would work on Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to both @mjy and @Matthias I have finally managed to figure out the minimal steps to take in order to make the recording work:

`sudo apt-get install pulseaudio jackd2 alsa-utils dbus-x11`

No need to play with `snd-dummy`, no need to create any additional config files... All these things only caused me to lose few hours :( After installing these packages on a clean Ubuntu server installation, I was able to run Python script and capture output audio to a file using PyAudio...

Comment: You are the man & Saved me hours <3
-- a note: you can check that this answer is working by typing `python3 -m sounddevice` in a terminal

Comment: Thanks! Was setting up baresip in debian netinst and ubuntu server and this worked like a charm.
My error message was "alsa could not open auplay device 'default' (no such file or directory)" for context

Comment: This is a great solution!

Answer (score 4):

If the application producing the sound supports [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/), this should be easy.
Then you only need to select the `dummy` driver for JACK and you can route the audio signal to any sound recording program you want (as long as it also supports JACK).

You'll need the package `jackd`, which has a command line interface for starting the JACK daemon.
The package `qjackctl` provides a nice GUI for experimenting with different settings and for making audio connections between programs. For recording, you can try the program `jack_rec` which is part of `jackd`, but there are many other recording application for JACK available as well.

If you want to use Python for recording, you can try the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) and [soundfile](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/) modules. If you need some JACK-specific functionality, you should try [jackclient-python](http://jackclient-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: How would I know, whether the application supports JACK?

Answer (score 1):

Install the PulseAudio.

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio
```

PulseAudio has emulation for ALSA.

Comment: Could you provide some further information on said emulation?

Comment: Emulation device will be created automatically. You probably will be able to record and play back in the ALSA emulation devices without setting.

Comment: already have pulse audio but how is this supposed to work?