# Creating a Virtual Sound Card on an EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, audio, amazon-ec2, alsa, soundcard

### Is there a way of creating a dummy sound card on an EC2 instance?

Unable to find snd-dummy, or any other other snd-modules using `modprobe`.

`sudo apt-get install linux-generic`, also didn't exactly help.

My goal is to run alsa with a dummy sound card.

`lscpi` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 IDE [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Cirrus Logic GD 5446
00:03.0 Unassigned class [ff80]: XenSource, Inc. Xen Platform Device (rev 01)
```

`uname` output:

```
Linux 5.4.0-1037-aws
```

`lsb_release -a` output:

```
No LSB modules are available. 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061291/linux-without-hardware-soundcard-capture-audio-playback-and-record-it-to-fil   `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio jackd2 alsa-utils dbus-x11`   let us know how you get on

Comment: any luck getting this setup??