# modprobe snd-dummy on linux server, ffmpeg -f alsa is recording noise

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, ffmpeg, alsa

Some people say that the parameter fake_buffer  can remove the noise, but I tried it and there is still noise

> modprobe snd-dummy fake_buffer=0

```
#modprobe snd-dummy fake_buffer=0 
# lsmod |grep snd
snd_dummy              24576  0
snd_pcm_oss            61440  0
snd_mixer_oss          28672  1 snd_pcm_oss
snd_pcm               118784  2 snd_pcm_oss,snd_dummy
snd_timer              36864  1 snd_pcm
snd                    94208  5 snd_timer,snd_pcm_oss,snd_pcm,snd_dummy,snd_mixer_oss
soundcore              16384  1 snd
# modinfo snd_dummy
filename:       /lib/modules/4.14.129-bbrplus/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-dummy.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Dummy soundcard (/dev/null)
author:         Jaroslav Kysela <perex@perex.cz>
depends:        snd-pcm,snd
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           snd_dummy
vermagic:       4.14.129-bbrplus SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           index:Index value for dummy soundcard. (array of int)
parm:           id:ID string for dummy soundcard. (array of charp)
parm:           enable:Enable this dummy soundcard. (array of bool)
parm:           model:Soundcard model. (array of charp)
parm:           pcm_devs:PCM devices # (0-4) for dummy driver. (array of int)
parm:           pcm_substreams:PCM substreams # (1-128) for dummy driver. (array of int)
parm:           fake_buffer:Fake buffer allocations. (bool)
parm:           hrtimer:Use hrtimer as the timer source. (bool)

#aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
dummy
default:CARD=Dummy
    Dummy, Dummy PCM
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=Dummy
    Dummy, Dummy PCM
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=Dummy,DEV=0
    Dummy, Dummy PCM
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Dummy,DEV=0
    Dummy, Dummy PCM
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Dummy,DEV=0
    Dummy, Dummy PCM
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Dummy,DEV=0
    Dummy, Dummy PCM
    Hardware device with all software conversions


# ffmpeg -f alsa  -i hw:0 -t 5  /dev/shm/out.mp3 -y
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, alsa, from 'hw:0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1616225206.353453, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp3, to '/dev/shm/out.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libmp3lame
size=      79kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate= 129.0kbits/s speed=   1x     
video:0kB audio:79kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.293899%
```

i use alsamixer to set all Volume to 0 ,and there is still noise
I searched in google for a long time and did not find other people have this problem  , where am I doing it wrong

Comment: i have get the answer.
that's dont't need snd-dummy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061291/linux-without-hardware-soundcard-capture-audio-playback-and-record-it-to-fil

Comment: I ran your example and it was silent !